# Mocking a global variable in pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

how do you mock a global variable in pytest? Here is a pair of example files:

File being tested, call it main.py:

```py
MY_GLOBAL = 1 
def foo():
    return MY_GLOBAL*2

def main()
    # some relevant invokation of foo somewhere here

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

File that is testing, call it test_main.py:

```py
from main import foo

class TestFoo(object):
    def test_that_it_multiplies_by_global(self):
        # expected=2, we could write, but anyway ...
        actual = foo()
        assert actual == expected
```

This is just a dummy example of course, but how would you go about mocking MY_GLOBAL and giving it another value?
Thanks in advance i've been kind of breaking my head over this and i bet it's really obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global variable is an attribute of the module, which you can patch using `patch.object`:

```
import main
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestFoo(object):
    def test_that_it_multiplies_by_global(self):
        with patch.object(main, 'MY_GLOBAL', 3):
            assert main.foo(4) == 12  # not 4
```

However, you want to make sure you are testing the right thing. Is `foo` supposed to multiply its argument by 1 (and the fact that it uses a global variable with a value of `1` an implementation detail), or is it supposed to multiply its argument by whatever value `MY_GLOBAL` has at the time of the call? The answer to that question will affect how you write your test.

Comment: sorry i realized i wrote something stupid, foo doesnt take arguments, anyway reading your answer now. i think patch.ob ject is what i was not finding in the docs

Comment: Same comment applies, though: should `foo` basically return a constant, whether or not `MY_GLOBAL` gets redefined, or is it really a function of the current value of `MY_GLOBAL`?

Comment: I'm getting an Attribute error, module does not have the attribute 'MY_GLOBAL'. hmm. Response to your comment: it is really a function of the current value. In 'reality' MY_GLOBAL is a set of dates that are established at the top of the script. I'm just trying to extrapolate

Comment: Is it `MY_GLOBAL` or `MYGLOBAL`? You use both in your question.

Comment: sorry, fixed the typo

Comment: `patch.object` is not required here.  `with patch("main.MY_GLOBAL", 3):` would be more usual.

Comment: @wim True; I'm not sure why I jumped to using `patch.object`.

Comment: i got it working using this info so i'll accept it. thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

It's useful to distinguish between module-level constants and global variables. The former are pretty common, but the latter are an anti-pattern in Python. You seem to have a module-level constant (read-only access to the var in normal production code). Global variables (R/W access in production code) should generally be refactored if possible.

For module constants:
If you can do so, it's generally more maintainable to refactor the functions that depend on module constants. This allows direct testing with alternate values as well as a single source of truth for the "constants" and backward compatibility. A minimal refactor is as simple as adding an optional parameter in each function that depends on the "constant" and doing a simple search-and-replace in that function, e.g.:

```
 def foo(value=MY_GLOBAL):
     return value*2
```

All other code can continue to call `foo()` as normal, but if you want to write tests with alternate values of `MY_GLOBAL`, you can simply call `foo(value=7484)`.

If what you want is an actual global, (with the `global` keyword and read/write access during production code, try [these alternatives](https://betterprogramming.pub/alternatives-to-using-globals-in-python-a3b2a7d5411b).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it overemphasizes the alternative to a global variable at the expense of the actual question.

Comment: I've downvoted. I disagree that it's useful to distinguish between module-level constants and global variables in Python.

Comment: i accepted the other answer sarah as it answered my question more narrowly, but I take your design advice to add the globals as default arguments. pretty clever!

Comment: @wim it's a distinction made in Google's Style guide ( https://betterprogramming.pub/alternatives-to-using-globals-in-python-a3b2a7d5411b section 2.5) and referenced in the article I linked: Global variables are discouraged; module-level constants are encouraged. It's also a distinction in Python syntax: Without the `global` keyword (which is _not_ present in the question), scoping rules prevent functions from modifying module-level constants.

Comment: @chepner Given OP's use case and sample code, "global variable" is not the right term. If OP needs global-variable behavior, I've got a link for that. My A is most responsive to the code and use-case they described, not the wording of the Q itself.

Comment: @SarahMesser Scoping rules do not prevent functions from modifying global-level "constants". `mock.patch`, which is a function, does just that (as the other answer demonstrates). There is no such thing as a "module constant" in Python, despite what the Google style guide says. It's only a convention that ALL_CAPS names will not be reassigned (except, perhaps, by test code).

Comment: @wim If OP was changing the value of `MY_GLOBAL` inside `foo()`, they'd need the `global` keyword. `mock.patch()` modifies the `main` object by assigning a new value to `main.MY_GLOBAL` - which is why it takes `main` as an argument, rather than modifying `MY_GLOBAL` directly. Moreover, it uses that altered value of `main` only inside a context manager (which is effectively a local function). To modify `MY_GLOBAL` without passing an argument into a function, and for actual global scope, you'd need the `global` keyword - which OP omits. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword

Comment: @SarahMesser No you wouldn't _need_ the global keyword. You can assign to `globals()["MY_GLOBAL"] = "something_else"`, or you can set the attribute on the module instance directly. And I'm not sure why you're going on a lesson about global mutable state in the first place, since the O.P.'s code shows no such issues.

Comment: Your suggested refactor of binding `value=MY_GLOBAL` at function definition time and then using a local var in the function actually creates additional complications, because now the default value exists in two different places (in `main.__dict__` and in `main.foo.__defaults__`). This can be problematic because now patching on the module var will have no effect for the function call. Such refactoring of the code under test may be advisable in a language which doesn't support monkeypatching, but for Python it is not necessary to restructure the O.P.'s code in order to test it adequately.